# Jekyll hangs with a slightly modified version of the generate_categories.rb plugin

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I use the `generate_categories.rb` plugin from [here](https://github.com/recurser/jekyll-plugins/blob/ef8e30b6f5e066f5e67fc596c7f698f3b7e54dfa/generate_categories.rb) to generate categories. However, if a category contains spaces I would like it's directory to be created with underscores.

For example, a category named "Metro Design Language" should be created in directory "Metro_Design_Language".

I took the original code and modified line 97,

from:

```
self.write_category_index(File.join(dir, category), category)
```

to:

```
self.write_category_index(File.join(dir, category.gsub(' ','_')), category)
```

However, for some reason now Jekyll can't generate the `_site` contents. After generating a few categories (with their indexes) it hangs.

I am new to Ruby and Jekyll, so any advice on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code.

Since GitHub does not allow the execution of plugins, check whether there is a `categories` directory outside the `_site` directory. If there are duplicates, Jekyll seems to hang because the underlying user privileges might not have the permissions to overwrite/replace a directory.

After deleting the `categories` directory outside the `_site` directory everything works.